# Mysql trigger optimization. Multiple table columns IFs (OLD.data <> NEW.data)

Tags: mysql, optimization, triggers

here I have a working MySQL trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_after_update_tbl1;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_after_update_tbl1
    AFTER UPDATE ON db1.tbl1 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    DECLARE strOld VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE strNew VARCHAR(255);
    SET strOld = '';
    SET strNew = '';

    IF (NEW.colA <> OLD.colA) THEN 
        SET strOld = CONCAT(strOld, 'colA: ',OLD.colA,'; ');
        SET strNew = CONCAT(strNew, 'colA: ',NEW.colA,'; ');
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.colB <> OLD.colB) THEN 
        SET strOld = CONCAT(strOld, 'colB: ',OLD.colB,'; ');
        SET strNew = CONCAT(strNew, 'colB: ',NEW.colB,'; ');
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.colC <> OLD.colC) THEN 
        SET strOld = CONCAT(strOld, 'colC: ',OLD.colC,'; ');
        SET strNew = CONCAT(strNew, 'colC: ',NEW.colC,'; ');
    END IF;
    -- AND SO MANY COLUMN CLAUSES ON....

    INSERT INTO db1.changes (user, tableName, oldData, newData, date)
    VALUES (
            user(), 
            'tableA', 
            strOld,
            strNew,
            now()
        );
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Is it possible to assign table column names to a variable (lets say X) from a list, array or something similar, iterate through it and use just one IF clause? Like in this (pseudocode):

```
BEGIN LOOP
        IF (NEW.X <> OLD.X) THEN 
            SET strOld = CONCAT(strOld, X, ': ',OLD.X,'; ');
            SET strNew = CONCAT(strNew, X, ': ',NEW.X,'; ');
        END IF;
END LOOP
```

Comment: "so many column..." -- will 255 be enough?

Comment: Yes, it will in fact :D

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the DBMS being used, what you are suggesting is normally known as **Dynamic SQL**, meaning that the statement that you are executing would first need to be compiled and then executed.

Though you may reduce the number of code lines, you will also be impacting (negatively) performance.

As I always say, *You write code once, but you read it many times and run it even much more times*. The moral: when needed, spend some additional effort to make your code readable and efficient.

In any case, MySQL provides [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) which is its version of Dynamic SQL.

There is one exception to what I wrote above: When your two tables contain a know number of columns, all of the same type. In such case, you can select the contents of the two records into two arrays and then loop through the arrays(this is just a last-minute thought though).